# Reference system nuget from .net standard library

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I tried adding some standard nugets to my .Net standard 2.0 library project. But when compiling I get the following type of errors:

```
The type 'IDisposable' exists in both 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and
'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

and

```
Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
```

Here is my project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.WebSockets" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Both nugets declare support for .Net Standard. I used VS 15.3 preview 2.

Is there some magic setting for .Net Standard 2.0 libraries I need to be aware of? What do I need to do to get a .Net standard 2.0 library compiling?

Comment: Update: In the list of hundreds of errors and warnings I found one missing nuget (websocket.client). Once installed the project builds. But error list still shows all previous errors. And it seems they are all intellisense errors. So maybe just a bug in VS 15.3 preview 2 ...

Comment: There have been a few bugs in the conflict resolution.. does that still repro with a daily build of preview 2? (download links at https://github.com/dotnet/cli/tree/release/2.0.0)

Comment: Thanks, updated to 2.0.0-preview2-006391 and intellisense back to normal. Wondering why it isn't bundled with VS installer from yesterday. .Net standard 2.0 seems quite useless without it ... make it an answer and I'll credit you for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to a bug in the conflict resolution targets / infrastructure that is fixed in current 2.0.0-preview2 builds. These aren't included in VS 2017 15.3 preview 2.0 and need to be installed separately (e.g. from the links in https://github.com/dotnet/cli/tree/release/2.0.0).

Note that VS 2017 15.3 now uses an "SDK resolver" that looks for a `global.json` in the opened project and uses the SDK version it resolves to (or latest) instead of the bundled SDKs.